# C# find all matching Items from a List<Item>

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say we have a `List<Product>` and each product item in the list has many `List<Type>`

```
public class Product{
public int Id {get:set;}
public string Name {get:set;}
public List<Type> Types {get;set;}
}

public class Type{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

After I create a product list, I need to group them by the type and then find all the belongs to each type. I think I should try `LINQ` for this. Here is what I have done so far, but seems not the right way to get the job done. May be someone can help me.

```
var productsList = new List<Product>();
//Adding products and types for each of them

var productTypesList = new Dictionary<int, string>();

 foreach (var p in productsList)
                            {
                                var pTypes = p.Types;
                                foreach (var ptype in
                                    pTypes.Where(x=> !productTypesList .ContainsKey(x.Id)))
                                {
                                    productTypesList.Add(ptype.Id, ptype.Name);
                                }
                            }
```

Then I'm trying to search Like this

```
foreach (var t in productTypesList)
{
var matches = productsList.FindAll(........); 
// from here I need to find all the product which belongs to type (t.id)

if (matches.Count > 0)
{
//Do somthing here
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
var productsPerType =
    from t in products.SelectMany(
        p => p.Types, (p, t) => new { Product = p, TypeId = t.Id })
    group t by t.TypeId
    into g
    select new { g.Key, Products = g.Select(x => x.Product) };
```

First, you do a `SelectMany` to get a list of all types inside the products. For each type you remember the type id and the corresponding product:

```
from t in products.SelectMany(
    p => p.Types, (p, t) => new { Product = p, TypeId = t.Id })
```

Each `t` is now an anonymous object containing a type id and a product. Next, you group these objects by type id. Now we have a group of products for each type id.

To give you an example, suppose you have the following products and types:

```
Product A -- Types 1, 2, 3
Product B -- Types 1
Product C -- Types 1, 3
```

The `SelectMany` gives the following intermediate result:

```
1, A
2, A
3, A
1, B
1, C
3, C
```

We group this result by type id so we get the following groups:

```
1, { A, B, C }
2, { A }
3, { A, C }
```

And this is the result you wanted.

Comment: Wildenburg - Your answer is also correct actually. But I saw the answer suggested by @Franchesca in the first place and Implmented it in my code. Thanks for the help guys. I'll mark this one also as an answer. (hope it's possible)

Comment: @randika I'm glad we could help :) You can only mark one answer, but I think Ronald probably deserves it for adding the IEqualityComparer stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
   var types = (from p in productsList
               from t in p.Types
               select t).Distinct(new TypeComparerById());
   var productsGrouped = (from t in types
                         select new 
                         {
                          Type = t,
                          ProductsPerType = productsList.Where(p=>p.Types.Any(pt=>pt.Id == t.Id))
                         }).ToList();
```

**Edit**

Ronald Wildenberg has correctly pointed that the call on Distinct() would work only if the instances are the same. To correct this I update with the following implementation

```
public class TypeComparerById : IEqualityComparer<Type>
{
    public bool Equals(Type t1, Type t2)
    {
        if (t1.Id == t2.Id)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }  

    public int GetHashCode(Type t)
    {
        return t.Id.GetHashCode();      
    }
}
```

You should pick his answer as being the correct one (although the next one is correct too)

Answer (score 0):

To find how many products are associated with each product type (where a product can have many types), you can first select all the distinct types like this

```
 var productTypeEqualityComparer = new ProductTypeEqualityComparer();
 var results = productsList.SelectMany(b => b.Types ).Distinct(productTypeEqualityComparer );
```

then you can make a list of all the products that contain each distinct type:

```
 Dictionary<Type, List<Product>> productsByProductType = new Dictionary<Type, List<Product>>()
 foreach (Type productType in results)
 {
      productsByProductType[productType] = productsList.Where(p => p.Types.Contains(productType, productTypeEqualityComparer )).ToList();
 }
```

Create your equality comparer like this:

```
 public class ProductTypeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Type>
{
    public bool Equals(Type x, Type y) {
 // I'm assuming here that the ID is unique to each type, but if it is 
        return x.Id == y.Id; 
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Type obj) {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

*Edited to add equality comparers

Comment: The call to `Distinct` only works if the `Type` objects from different products refer to the same instances. If this is not the case, all of the `Type` objects are distinct. This can be fixed by having `Type` implement `IEquatable<Type>` or by passing an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<Type>` to `Distinct()`.

Comment: @Franchesca - seems like selecting distinct Types not working.

Comment: Then you need to do what Ronald Wildenberg is suggesting, and create an IEqualityComparer<Type> for your product type. I will update my answer to include that.

Comment: @Franchesca   - I tried what you sugessted and it worked for me. Plus i did some modification to your ProductTypeEqualityComparer class to inherit from IEqualityComparer<Type> (May not be visible to everyone yet)

Answer (score -1):

> Then I'm trying to search Like this

For that you don't need a dictionary...

Code:

```
var productsList = new List<Product>();
productsList.Add(new Product { Id = 1, Name = "p1", Types = new List<Type>() { new Type() { Id = 1, Name = "ptype1" }, new Type() { Id = 2, Name = "ptype2" } } });
productsList.Add(new Product { Id = 2, Name = "p2", Types = new List<Type>() { new Type() { Id = 1, Name = "ptype1" } } });
productsList.Add(new Product { Id = 3, Name = "p3", Types = new List<Type>() { new Type() { Id = 2, Name = "ptype2" } } });
productsList.Add(new Product { Id = 4, Name = "p4", Types = new List<Type>() { new Type() { Id = 2, Name = "ptype2" }, new Type() { Id = 3, Name = "type3" } } });

// this is an IEnumerable<Type> (types with the same Id and different name will take only the first)
var productTypesList = (from p in productsList      // for each product
                        from t in p.Types           // for each type in product
                        group t by t.Id into types  // group em by Id into types
                        select types.First());      // but use only the first (else this would be an IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type>>

Console.WriteLine("Types:");

//EDIT: Since Francesca had some complains, and thought having a dictionary from this is difficult, here is a one liner to do that.
// This can be done by surrounding the query above with parenthesis and adding the ToDictionary() call at the end
// I prefer not to use a dictionary unless needed and your code seems not to need it since you need to loop on product types, as stated at the end of the question
// Use this only if you need to store or pass around these values. if you do, you loose potential other properties of your types.
var prodTypeDict = productTypesList.ToDictionary(v => v.Id, v => v.Name);

foreach (var p in productTypesList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Id + " " + p.Name);
}

foreach (var type in productTypesList)
{
    // this is an IEnumerable<Product>
    var products = from p in productsList                   // for each product
                   where p.Types.Any(t => t.Id == type.Id)  // that has this type
                   select p;

    Console.WriteLine("Products of type: " + type.Name);
    foreach (var p in products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Id + " " + p.Name);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Types:
1 ptype1
2 ptype2
3 type3
Products of type: ptype1
1 p1
2 p2
Products of type: ptype2
1 p1
3 p3
4 p4
Products of type: type3
4 p4
```

Comment: You may not specifically need a dictionary, but it is nice to organise the information in some sort of collection where it can be used elsewhere in your program. The writer of the question didn't specify what they were going to use that information for, and I don't think writing it out to the console is particularly useful :)

Comment: Francesca I updated the above code with an explanation. And the op stated how it want to use the information at the end of the question.  I won't comment on the Console.WriteLine part. Console.WriteLine could actually be something else :=)

Comment: And by the way IQueryable<Type> is some sort of collection anytime you write ToList() on it, plus it can be passed around elsewhere in the program, and the creation of the list can be delayed to where needed. It would be nice for those that are giving -1 to explain themselves if they find themselves rightful to do that.