# How to get lines from a file between 2 dynamic locations?

Tags: c#, .net

As noted in a thread I asked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110524/how-to-loop-over-a-list-while-its-contents-contain-a-subvalue), I'm trying to parse some segments of code from a single method that is over 8K lines long. It's mostly just duplicated, hardcoded logic for a bunch of fields in a dataset.

Sample data I'm parsing would look something like this;

```
temp_str = ds->Fields->FieldsByName("Field1")->AsString;
if (temp_str.IsEmpty())
    //do something
else
    //do something else

temp_str = ds->Fields-FieldsByName("Field2")->AsString;
if (differentCondition)
    //do something
else
    //do some other thing
```

In essence, what I want to do is get all lines between the each "pair" of `temp_str = ...` lines and then just collect each unique set of validation rules. But I'm having a little trouble locating these segments of code.

My method looks like this:

```
while (lines.Any(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(validationHeader)))
{
    startOfNextValidation = lines.IndexOf(lines.First(s => s.Contains(validationHeader)), lines.IndexOf(validationHeader) + 1);

    if (startOfNextValidation > lines.Count || startOfNextValidation <= 0)
        break;

    validations.Add(GetString(lines.GetRange(0, startOfNextValidation)));
    lines.RemoveRange(0, startOfNextValidation);
}
```

The `string validationHeader` variable is just `temp_str = ds->Fields->FieldsByName("`.

This successfully identifies my first chunk of validation, but then it doesn't find anything else, which is incorrect. There's something wrong with how I'm identifying instances of `validationHeader` on the first line in my `while` loop, but I cannot seem to discern where the logic error is.

How can I find the "pairs" of `validationHeader`s and then get the lines between these pairs?

I saw these SO threads but I don't really understand how to 'translate' it for my purposes;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20360426/1189566

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6562086/1189566

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the indexes of list that contains a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305397/how-to-get-the-indexes-of-list-that-contains-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Wound up with this solution:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList<string>();
List<string> validations = new List<string>();
List<int> allIndices = lines.Select((s, i) => new { Str = s, Index = i })
    .Where(x => x.Str.Contains(validationHeader))
    .Select(x => x.Index).ToList<int>();

for (int j = 0; j < allIndices.Count() - 1; j++)
{
    int count = (allIndices[j + 1] - allIndices[j]);
    validations.Add(GetString(lines.GetRange(allIndices[j], count)));
}
```

`lines` contains all of the code from `file`

`vaidations` contains the segments of code between the `validationHeader` defined in my original question

`allIndices` just contains the index of each `validationHeader`

`GetString(List<string>)` just returns a single string containing all of the elements within the given range, which is then added to my `validations` list which I later loop over with `foreach var v in validations.Distinct()` and write `v` to a file.